# Meaning of ARM assembly instruction #(2*4)

Tags: assembly, cortex-m

During a gdb session, I came across a assembly instruction as follows

```
mov r0, #(2*4)
```

As I understand # is literal, it suppose to supply a constant instead of an operation. Am I understand it correctly?

p.s As I understand, this is assign 8 to register r0, am I right?

Comment: Yes. Since you are in gdb you can verify it easily by printing the value in the register.

Comment: Thank @Jester, my program crashes on that instruction, that's why I try to understand it.

Comment: That can't crash unless maybe it's in non-executable memory. Also, if you are really seeing it in that form that means you are looking at source code so maybe you have a mismatch with the actual binary. Try `x/i $pc` at the crash to disassemble the faulting instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

understand that assembly language is defined by the assembler, the tool, so if this is supported at all it is tool specific, assuming it is supported this does look like a constant/immediate.

```
mov r0,#(2*4)
```

assemble then disassemble

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e3a00008    mov r0, #8
```

so for this version of gnu assembler yes it does just that.  sometimes when you see syntax like that it is not real assembly (like using #defines) and you need to run it through gcc's preprocessor

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e3a00008    mov r0, #8
```

wasnt required in this case, for this version of gnu assembler with an arm target.